# Having error: -22 while developing usb hid device

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, hid, usb-hid

Hello we're trying to get an usb-hid device working on linux system.(Currently Rpi-2B Buildroot 64bit)

But dmesg shows an error on device plugged in, while other keyboards/mouse work fine.

The error **-22** isn't found with googling so I am stucking here.

Wondering what the code means or where to find the full error list. Or what our hw team can do to fix this.

[image: Error Image]

Does anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L26

Answer (score 0):

`-22` is `EINVAL` [defined as](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L26):

```cpp
#define EINVAL      22  /* Invalid argument */
```

(usb subsystem returns negative error codes)

This error text comes from [these lines](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/usbhid/hid-core.c#L1424-L1428):

```cpp
ret = hid_add_device(hid);
if (ret) {
    hid_err(hid, "can't add hid device: %d\n", ret);
    goto err_connection_disable;
}
```

You can try to [increase linux kernel loglevel](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-the-linux-kernel-log-levels) to find the exact cause.